# JQuery Mobile do X to every div with given class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a JQuery mobile site which has an image slider on 2 pages. The sliders are activated using the following JS:

```
$(function () {
   $("#slider").excoloSlider();
});
```

where '#slider' is the name of the div that gets rendered as the slider.

I have this slider on the 2 pages and have given both the same id, and don't want to insert the above code into both pages. To make things easy I want to be able to make add the above code into a.js file that I'm referencing at the top of both pages.

However, the script only kicks in when one of the pages are the first page to be navigated to. So, I assume this means the code is only being called in the once, and due to the AJAX loading of the subsequent page, it isnt called when this new page loads.

So, how can I run the code to affect any/all pages which feature the slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how many times you have to call `.excoloSlider();` function. In case you have to call it each time the page is visited, then you need to use any of these *page events*, `pagecontainershow` or `pagecontainerbeforeshow`.

If you use `pagecontainershow`, you can run `.excoloSlider();` on `#slider` even if you have the same id in a different page. This way, you specify in which page to look for `#slider`.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
  var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
  /* check if #slider is within active page */
  var slider = activePage.find("#slider").not(".slider");
  if(slider) {
     slider.excoloSlider();
  }
});
```

#### Update

I have added `.not(".slider")` selector to exclude already rendered *slider*. The function `.excoloSlider()` will be called on new sliders only.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8kQ2g/)**

Comment: Haha! I was waiting for you to show up @Omar I'm dissapointed it took you so long. ;-)

Comment: haha @PhillHealey I was busy with the kids ;) I'll update my answer as I was testing it. Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8kQ2g/

Comment: I've not had chance to try it yet but it looks promising. Just wondering why you've put a hash on the first slider and a dot on the second. Shouldn't these be the same and reflect whether slide is a class or I'd ?

Comment: @phillhealey the hash is for id, the `.not(".slider")` is to exclude any slider that has this class. That plugin you're using, adds `.slider` to a slider when you run `.excoloslider()` on it. If you run it again on the same slider, it'll malfunction.

Comment: Does it? Oh, ok. Now you know the plugin Im using, better than I do. Typical. ;-))))

Comment: @PhillHealey I've figured it our while testing my code. I hope it works for you :)

Comment: It appears to. I noticed an odd behaviour with the other sliders on the same page that then ran fine. I'll check again tomorrow. Hopefully it was a one off.

Comment: @PhillHealey let me know if you still need help.

Comment: yup its still doing it. Take a look at this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8kQ2g/2/

Comment: @PhillHealey fixed http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dpLs6/ you're using  initializing other sliders (sliderb, sliderc) when jQM framework is initialized. Check update code in fiddle.

Comment: Excellent thanks. Im trying to build a light weight theme for colleagues to use on some projects. Is there any real overhead to adding in 'sliderb & 'sliderc' if they didn't exist???

Comment: Ah! Just realised, that doesn't fix my issue, since I need to initialise the other sliders with options.

Comment: Ive tried to have a go but cant get the 3rd slider with options to run. It just breaks the other two: http://jsfiddle.net/dpLs6/5/

Comment: @PhillHealey you can use different variables based on id. E.g. `var sliderC = activePage.find("#sliderC").exoSlider({ options });`.

Comment: I know, try it though. I did that for sliderc and it just stopped them all from working. Dunno why.

Comment: @PhillHealey http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/fUME3/ each slider with its' own _options_. I forgot to add `.not(".slider")` in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a similar thing but for some reason it wouldn't work. Well, as always I'm really greatful for the help @Omar !!!

Comment: @PhillHealey I'm glad I've been of help :)

Comment: I spoke too soon. Sliders b & c still don't work. Also slider on the second page doesn't work if I enter the 'site' via the page featuring the 3 sliders. However, if I then navigate to the index page, #slider on index does work.

Comment: @PhillHealey first of all, you really don't need to "tick" my answer as correct, i won't be annoyed :) Of course it won't work because you navigate directly to subpages without passing through first page (_Multi-Page Model_). If you're using _Single Page Model_, make sure you have custom JS in `head` of each HTML file.

Comment: ok forget that. It looks like it was some sticky caching going on. A few refreshes and it all seems to be working well now. Fingers crossed! Thanks again.

Comment: your answer is correct. I only untick it in case you go AWOL. I thought it might encourage others to join in. I hate feeling like you are my exclusive JQuery Shaolin Master. ;-)) I have got the JS on ALL pages. The weird thing was that 'slider' was working on both pages, but sliderb and sliderc werent working. Anyway, see my previous comment. It looks like it was a caching issue. All seems to be working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: @phillhealey if my answers are annoying you, I can stop answering any questions of yours. I reply any comment of any of my old/recent answers. I'm here to help not to collect rep :) good luck on your project! Ps: I'll keep answering your questions :P

Comment: @PhillHealey this is kind of you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use class instead of id since `id` is unique, then you can change your jQuery code to:

```
$(function () {
   $(".slider").excoloSlider();
});
```

Comment: The problem with that is, it would require rewriting the JQuery plugin that controls the slider.

Comment: actually no thats a lie. It shouldnt affect the plugin. Ill go try it.

Comment: @PhillHealey, This is a good way to go, but instead of putting it within $(function(){}, put it within the jQM $(document).on("pagecreate",...) for all pages that include the slider.

Comment: @ezanker would you mind expanding that a little. Im that too well versed on JQuery / Mobile

Comment: @Felix That kinda works except on the navigating to the 2nd page I only see the 'pager' dots and not the images. So I can see the slider is moving between slides, but the images aren't there. The same thing happens if I were to put the code before the html that identifies the slider images. So to me it looks like this method is running before the page has been fully rendered and the JQuery has access to the images.

Comment: @ezanker Like this? $(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
   $(".slider").excoloSlider();
    });

Comment: @ezanker That has the same effect. The secondary page doesn't show any images. The slider pager is bisible and moving but no images. Also the pager is double up eg 2 versions. To me this suggests that the script is running twice on the same div.

Comment: Weirdly both methods mentioned above break the 2 other sliders I have on the 2nd page. For testing purposes I have this initialised by onpage js. So its odd that they also get broken by these methods.

Comment: Try giving the 2 sliders unique ids but same class ("slider"). The have separate pagecreate for each page containing a slider:$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1",function () { $(".slider").excoloSlider(); }); and $(document).on("pagecreate", "#page2",function () { $(".slider").excoloSlider(); });

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Mobile API for the  [navigation system](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.navigate/)

```
$(window).on( "navigate", function( event, data ) {
  $("#slider").excoloSlider();
});
```

**Edit**

Use [pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/)

From the [jQM docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html):

> Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

Comment: Now it only works on the first page loaded and not subsequent pages. If i return back to the initial page on which it worked it also now, no longer works.